# Making selected text bold in an NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, foundation

I'm using the following code to make selected text bold in an NSTextView

```
  [self.textView.attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] range:self.textView.selectedRange];
```

Where self.textView is an outlet to an NSTextView . Xcode gives a warning that addAttribute may not work as the property is of type NSAttributedString and not NSMutableAttributedString.The code works but is it wrong to do it this way ? If so what is the proper way ?

UPDATE : 
I found another way of doing this :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *textFieldText = [self.textView.attributedString mutableCopy];
[textFieldText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] range:self.textView.selectedRange];
[self.textView.textStorage setAttributedString:textFieldText];
```

Since both methods work , I'd like to know which is better.

Comment: I think your update is the way to go.

Comment: i think your solution os the only right way. Don't forget to release/autorelease a copied object, copy do increment retain counter.(If you don't use ARC)

Comment: Noone here who knows where I can find the authoritative answer to those .. I tried looking around on developer.apple.com ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General Remarks

Take the interface that a class exposes at its word.  It is not best practice to assume that the return type is a specific subclass of the declared return type.

This is especially important in the context of a class cluster: different implementations of the common interface may have different different return types for the same method though those return types are guaranteed to be compatible with the type declared in the header.

Supposing you could be guaranteed that all undocumented subclasses in the class cluster presently return the same specific subclass of the type declared in the header, you cannot be guaranteed that that will remain the case in future revisions of Apple's frameworks.

#### NSTextView

The question is about an `NSTextView`'s and its property `textStorage`.  This property is of type `NSTextStorage`, a "semiconcrete subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString`".  The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) goes on, describing the preferred mechanism for changing the string stored by the `NSTextStorage` or its attributes:

> use the text access methods defined by NSMutableAttributedString, NSAttributedString, NSMutableString, and NSString to perform character-level manipulation.

`NSTextView` exposes its property `textStorage` which is an instance of `NSTextStorage`.  `NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString`.  Consequently, we can simply add our attribute to it:

```
[self.textView.textStorage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                                  value:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f]
                                  range:self.textView.selectedRange];
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you can provide the "correct" code for doing this.

Comment: I guess i wasnt diligent enough to dig into the documentation ... but its quite a jungle.

Comment: indeed it is.  this approach is the one that the documentation recommends, though.